# AWS S3 direct upload returns invalid signature (version 4 signature)

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm sick of seeing this response:

> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.

I know a version this question has been answered here:

[SO - AWS S3 browser upload using HTTP POST gives invalid signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40819360/aws-s3-browser-upload-using-http-post-gives-invalid-signature)

And I have followed every detail of it with no luck, and I'm probably missing something simple. I'm using C# to generate a policy and v4 Aws signature. Here is the policy code:

```
var policyBuilder = new StringBuilder();

policyBuilder.AppendFormat("{{ \"expiration\": \"{0}\",\r\n", "2017-12-30T12:00:00.000Z");
policyBuilder.Append("  \"conditions\": [\r\n");
policyBuilder.Append("    [\"starts-with\", \"$key\", \"\"],\r\n");
policyBuilder.AppendFormat("    {{\"x-amz-credential\": \"{1}\"}},\r\n",  <MyAccessKey>/20170214/us-east-2/s3/aws4_request));
policyBuilder.Append("    {\"x-amz-algorithm\": \"AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\"},\r\n");
policyBuilder.Append("    {\"x-amz-date\": \"20170214T000000Z\" }\r\n");
policyBuilder.Append("  ]\r\n}");

var policyString = policyBuilder.ToString();
var policyStringBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(policyString);
return Convert.ToBase64String(policyStringBytes);
```

This is the code used to generate the signature:

```
static byte[] HmacSHA256(String data, byte[] key)
{
    String algorithm = "HmacSHA256";
    KeyedHashAlgorithm kha = KeyedHashAlgorithm.Create(algorithm);
    kha.Key = key;

    return kha.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));
}

static byte[] GetSignatureKey(String key, String dateStamp, String regionName, String serviceName)
{
    byte[] kSecret = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(("AWS4" + key).ToCharArray());
    byte[] kDate = HmacSHA256(dateStamp, kSecret);
    byte[] kRegion = HmacSHA256(regionName, kDate);
    byte[] kService = HmacSHA256(serviceName, kRegion);
    byte[] kSigning = HmacSHA256("aws4_request", kService);

    return kSigning;
}

public static string ToHexString(byte[] data, bool lowercase)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (var i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(data[i].ToString(lowercase ? "x2" : "X2"));
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

The method that brings it all together:

```
public string GetS3PolicySignatureV4(string policy)
{
    byte[] signingKey = GetSignatureKey(<MySecretKey>, "20170214T000000Z", "us-east-2", "s3");
    byte[] signature = HmacSHA256(policy, signingKey);
    return AWS4SignerBase.ToHexString(signature, true);
}
```

Here is the html form:

```
<form action="http://<BucketName>.s3.amazonaws.com/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="key" value="<FileKey>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="x-amz-credential" value="<MyAccessKey>/20170214/us-east-2/s3/aws4_request"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="x-amz-algorithm" value="AWS4-HMAC-SHA256" />
    <input type="hidden" name="x-amz-date" value="20170214T000000Z" />
    <input type="hidden" name="policy" value='<Base64PolicyResult>' />
    <input type="hidden" name="x-amz-signature" value="<GenerateSignature>" />
    File:
    <input type="file" name="file" /> <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload to Amazon S3" />
</form>
```

I have verified that the example policy result in this example:

[AWS - Examples: Browser-Based Upload using HTTP POST (Using AWS Signature Version 4)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html)

as well as the resulting signature matched the example using the provided parameters and keys. But when I try to POST to S3, I always get that dreaded response.

Comment: I think I found Waldo. From the example, `{"bucket": "sigv4examplebucket"},` is missing from your policy document.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I've tried it with the "bucket" in the policy as well, in fact all the policy options included in that example. According to this http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-authentication-HTTPPOST.html the only elements in the policy that are required are: x-amz-algorithm, x-amz-credential and x-amz-date. Based on the method for calculating the signature (which I got from here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-examples.html#signature-v4-examples-dotnet) the contents of the policy should not matter to calculate the signature.

Comment: What?! Noooooo.  That's the algorithm for creating the *signing key* -- not the signature.  You use the signing key to create a signature *of* the policy's base64 representation.  A single byte different in the policy changes the signature dramatically.  The signature is protecting the policy against tampering and then the policy determines whether the request is valid because the form matches the policy.

Comment: Also your interpretation of minimum policy fields is incorrect. In the policy, "[you must specify one condition for each form field that you specify in the form... Each form field that you specify in a form (except x-amz-signature, file, policy, and field names that have an x-ignore- prefix) must appear in the list of conditions."](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-HTTPPOSTConstructPolicy.html#sigv4-ConditionMatching)

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot right, mix up of terminology on my part. The policy is the signing key, which is used to calculate the signature using the same info, i.e. secret key, date, region, and service. But still, the bucket is not required in the policy to calculate the signature. It will balk for not having the bucket once Aws matches the signature and then reads the values within the policy, the issue I was trying to get past was the mismatched signatures. I did just figure out the issue. Answer to come next...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was that the date passed into the GetSignatureKey method was incorrectly formatted. Should have just been "20170214" and the hidden form field x-amz-date is the ISO8601 format of "20170214T000000Z". I was passing in the same value into the GetSignatureKey method.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to use the same code as you posted and I changed the date as you mentioned in the answer. Still I am getting the same error. @gsxrboy73 Do you have any idea? also I post my question here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49184746/aws-s3-direct-upload-returns-invalid-signature-version-4-signature-c-sharp