# AWS S3 direct upload returns invalid signature (version 4 signature) C#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, post, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload file to Amazon S3 directly from browser. I read the documentation and followed the example [provided by amazon](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-examples-using-sdks.html)

the example methods works except post method. the error message is **The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.**

I also checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42237602/aws-s3-direct-upload-returns-invalid-signature-version-4-signature) code sample. and applied the answer to the code and still getting the same error.

```
public class PolicyBuilder
{
    public static string Key = "Key";
    public static string Secret = "Secret";

    public static string GetS3PolicySignatureV4()
    {
        var policyBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        policyBuilder.AppendFormat("{{ \"expiration\": \"{0}\",\r\n", "2018-12-30T12:00:00.000Z");
        policyBuilder.Append("  \"conditions\": [\r\n");
        policyBuilder.Append("    [\"starts-with\", \"$key\", \"\"],\r\n");
        policyBuilder.AppendFormat("    {{\"x-amz-credential\": \"{0}\"}},\r\n",  Key + "/20180308/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request");
        policyBuilder.Append("    {\"x-amz-algorithm\": \"AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\"},\r\n");
        policyBuilder.Append("    {\"x-amz-date\": \"20180308T000000Z\" }\r\n");
        policyBuilder.Append("  ]\r\n}");

        var policyString = policyBuilder.ToString();
        var policyStringBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(policyString);
        var policy = Convert.ToBase64String(policyStringBytes);

        byte[] signingKey = GetSignatureKey(Key, "20180308", "us-east-1", "s3");
        byte[] signature = HmacSHA256(policy, signingKey);
        var sig = ToHexString(signature, true);
        return sig;
    }

    static byte[] HmacSHA256(String data, byte[] key)
    {
        String algorithm = "HmacSHA256";
        KeyedHashAlgorithm kha = KeyedHashAlgorithm.Create(algorithm);
        kha.Key = key;

        return kha.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));
    }

    static byte[] GetSignatureKey(String key, String dateStamp, String regionName, String serviceName)
    {
        byte[] kSecret = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(("AWS4" + key).ToCharArray());
        byte[] kDate = HmacSHA256(dateStamp, kSecret);
        byte[] kRegion = HmacSHA256(regionName, kDate);
        byte[] kService = HmacSHA256(serviceName, kRegion);
        byte[] kSigning = HmacSHA256("aws4_request", kService);

        return kSigning;
    }

    public static string ToHexString(byte[] data, bool lowercase)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (var i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(data[i].ToString(lowercase ? "x2" : "X2"));
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

and here is the form:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="http://MyBucket.s3.amazonaws.com/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="key" value="/images/a5827206-ea2c-4fc6-a66b-aebde27d0ea3.jpg" />
        <input type="hidden" name="x-amz-credential" value="Key/20180308/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request" />
        <input type="hidden" name="x-amz-algorithm" value="AWS4-HMAC-SHA256" />
        <input type="hidden" name="x-amz-date" value="20180308T000000Z" />
        <input type="hidden" name="policy" value='<Base64PolicyResult>' />
        <input type="hidden" name="x-amz-signature" value="<GenerateSignature>" />
        File:
        <input type="file" name="file" /> <br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload to Amazon S3" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am still getting the same error. Should I set any specific policy for my bucket on amazon s3?
is there anything wrong in my code? :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is here...

```
byte[] signingKey = GetSignatureKey(Key, "20180308", "us-east-1", "s3");
```

This line should be...

```
byte[] signingKey = GetSignatureKey(Secret, "20180308", "us-east-1", "s3");
```

You're using the aws-access-key-id rather than the secret key to generate your signing key.

Comment: Thank you so much.